# swapping div content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a pretty sweet codepen regarding buttons/aesthestics and re-purposed it to fit what our team is trying to build.  Basically we want buttons going down vertically on the left hand side with a large div on the right hand side.  When a certain button is clicked on the left, the div on the right will change to show the appropriate content.  After doing some reading, it looks like jQuery is the answer to this functionality.  I've never actually coded jQuery and couldn't get anything to work correctly yet.  There are two things we need:

- When the button is clicked on the left, we need the div on the right to change content.
- When the button on the left is active, I want the styling to remain what it looks like when it's hovered.

Can someone provide some guidance?  Thanks!

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.bt_wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  perspective: 200px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  perspective-origin: 50px 50px;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.icon,
.icon2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 30px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.icon2 {
  background: black;
  transform: translate3d(29px, 0px, 0px) rotateY(90deg);
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
}

.bt_wrap:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.bt_wrap:hover .icon {
  background: black;
}

.bt_wrap:hover .icon2 {
  background: black;
  color: blue;
}

.bt_wrap:hover .box {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.started {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  color: green;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 4px;
  background: orange;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -otransform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="wrapper" class="steps">
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="1">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-clipboard">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.questionnaire}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-clipboard">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.questionnaire}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="2">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-building">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.work_history}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-building">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.work_history}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="3">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-users">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.beneficiaries}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-users">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.beneficiaries}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="4">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-university">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.tax}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-university">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.tax}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="5">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="form-container">
      <h2 class="form-title">Welcome to Your Employment Guide!</h2>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
      <div class="text-center">
        <input type="button" value="NEXT" class="btn btn-primary next">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: paste code in question - not as link

Comment: Fiddle working: [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/yundlu/xwts23gp/9/)

Comment: Look into SPA (single page applications). Look into AJAX (no specifically JQuery, but JQuery has a great implementation). The rest is basic HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Comment: as you have tried to con the system by adding a %20 in front of your fiddle link, it now doesn't work.  Please don't ignore the rules of SO - links to js fiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Comment: If the content is already loaded when the page loads then this is really just tabs.  If the data loads on click then it will be AJAX + JQuery (as one option).

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxmaqtd3/

**When the button is clicked on the left, we need the div on the right to change content.**

My solution uses jquery [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to show and hide divs which contain slide content. You will need to include all the content in your html with unique IDs (i.e. `#slide1`, `#slide2`, `#slide3`, etc) and use the css `display: none` on all slides except the first (or default) slide.

This solution uses a custom [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the ID of the slide div which you want the given button to show. For example:

```
<div class="bt_wrap" name="1" data-slide="slide1">
```

**When the button on the left is active, I want the styling to remain what it looks like when it's hovered.**

To achieve this I duplicate the `:hover` styles into a new class called `active` when you click on one of the button divs it [removes the class](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) from all buttons and then [adds the class](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to the button you have just clicked.

JS:

```
$('.bt_wrap').click(function(){
    $('.bt_wrap').removeClass('active'); //remove active class on all buttons
    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to the one that you clicked 

  var slideId = $(this).attr('data-slide'); //find the value of the associated slide id 

  $('.slide').not("#" + slideId).hide(); //hid all slides except the one you want to show

  $("#" + slideId).show(); //show the one you want to show

});
```

CSS:

```
#slide1 {
  display: block;
}

#slide2 {
  display: none;
}

.active .box {
   transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.active {
    background: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<div class="main">
  <div id="wrapper" class="steps">
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="1" data-slide="slide1">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-clipboard">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.questionnaire}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-clipboard">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.questionnaire}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="2" data-slide="slide2">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-building">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.work_history}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-building">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.work_history}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="3">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-users">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.beneficiaries}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-users">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.beneficiaries}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="4">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-university">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.tax}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-university">
          <span ng-class="{'started': c.data.tax}" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bt_wrap" name="5">
      <div class="box">
        <i class="icon fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
        <i class="icon2 fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide form-container">
      <h2 class="form-title">Welcome to Your Employment Guide!</h2>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
      <div class="text-center">
        <input type="button" value="NEXT" class="btn btn-primary next">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slide2" class="slide form-container">
      <h2 class="form-title">Some other title</h2>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </h4>
      <div class="text-center">
        <input type="button" value="NEXT" class="btn btn-primary next">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```